# Saving Ember model with property setter

Tags: ember.js

I have a property setter for an edit controller, which returns date in nice format and parses user's input. It works well as long as I don't save a model. Save action commits all changes except date and reverts it to the previous value. Before hitting a save button everything is ok, I mean date changes when user types in a new one, but save action updates only fields modified directly.

Why model in save action is different from model that is rendered and modified by a setter?

```
App.TaskEditController = Em.ObjectController.extend
  dateValue: ((key, value)->
    model = @get 'model'
    if arguments.length is 1
      date = model.get 'date'
      return moment(date).format 'YYYY-MM-DD'
    newValue = value
    # do something with newValue here
    model.set 'date', newValue
    return newValue
  ).property 'date'

  actions:
    save: ->
      model = @get 'model'
      # model.get 'date' returns previous value
      model.save()
```

Comment: Just a thought but on first glance  it looks like the get model in the save action is getting the same model as in the dateValue. They are querying the same place. Because you dont save the date to the model in dateValue the get is "getting" the "old" version. Have you tried removing `model = @get 'model'` from the save action, and use `this.model` or instead save the model after  `model.set 'date', newValue`

Comment: I think I found the answer - date serializer returns null if value has type different than Date. I was testing this code on item which has no date, so I assumed that date was reverted to previous value.